# Angular - ng-hide animation doesn't fully hide

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

**The repo is here: https://github.com/sjzerneri/mad-lib-project/ and the live preview is here:  http://sjzerneri.github.io/mad-lib-project/**

I have an ng-hide in my html that operates correctly before I start trying to adjust the css to animate it.

When I try to animate it with ng-hide-add and ng-hide-remove, the section fades out, and then promptly reappears instead of hiding. Why doesn't the section stay hidden?

Here's my HTML for the section:

```
 <section class="word-inputs" ng-hide="hideForm && myForm.$valid">
    <h3> Provide The Following Words:</h3>
    <div class="all-words">
        <form name="myForm" ng-submit="submitted=true;submit()">
            <div class="word-selection">
                <input type="text" ng-model="name" placeholder="name" required>
                <input type="text" ng-model="jobtitle" placeholder="job title" required>
                <input type="text" ng-model="tedioustask" placeholder="tedious task" required>
            </div>
            <div class="word-selection">
                <input type="text" ng-model="dirtytask" placeholder="dirty task" required>
                <input type="text" ng-model="celebrity" placeholder="celebrity" required>
                <input type="text" ng-model="uselessskill" placeholder="useless skill" required>
            </div>
            <div class="word-selection">
                <input type="text" ng-model="obnoxiousceleb" placeholder="obnoxious celeb" required>
                <input type="number" ng-model="hugenumber" placeholder="huge number" required>
                <input type="text" ng-model="adjective" placeholder="adjective" required>
            </div>
            <div class="hor-line"> </div>
            <div class="submission">
                <button type="submit">Generate Mad Lib</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

</section>
```

Here's my css:

```
.word-inputs {
    padding-top: 2rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 90%;
    text-align: center;
}

.word-inputs.ng-hide-add,
.word-inputs.ng-hide-remove {
    -webkit-transition: all linear 1s;
    -moz-transition: all linear 1s;
    -o-transition: all linear 1s;
    transition: all linear 1s;
    display: block!important;
}

.word-inputs.ng-hide-add.ng-hide-add-active,
.word-inputs.ng-hide-remove {
    opacity: 0;
}

.word-inputs.ng-hide-add,
.word-inputs.ng-hide-remove.ng-hide-remove-active {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: The repo is here: https://github.com/sjzerneri/mad-lib-project/ and the live preview is here:  http://sjzerneri.github.io/mad-lib-project/

Answer (score 0):

Add an extra div for your animation class
like

```
<section  ng-hide="hideForm && myForm.$valid">
    <div class="word-inputs" >
        <h3> Provide The Following Words:</h3>
        .....
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: The ng-hide works in that scenario, but the animation is no longer in effect. Any thoughts on how come?